# What happens to the voltmeter

Tags: circuit-analysis

What happens to voltmeter reading when we increase R' (The rheostat)?[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only a hint:

Redraw the circuit in the conventional manner, battery on the left with positive on top and negative connected to GND on the bottom.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcVOT3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawn schematic.*

Now, what happens to voltmeter reading when we increase R1?

Comment: I see that R1 will consume a higher voltage then the voltage that R2 gets will be lower .. Right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Note that if English is not your first language then you should say that in your user profile so we can help you out.